# gganimate::transition_time() transitions between non-existing observations

Tags: r, animation, ggplot2, gganimate

I'm trying to get more familiar with the `gganimate` package. In doing so,  I noticed that `transition_time(time)` does not seem to necessarily use the exact values in `time` but sort of fills in. In the below `data.frame` there are 41 dates in the `time` variable. From what I understand, I would expect `transition_time(time)` to only transition between those 41 dates.

In the below code, I also use `geom_rect` to color the background based on the values in `category`. Looking at the outputted `df.gif`, when the background is white, `transition_time(time)` seem to use a value of `time` for which there are no real observations. Furthermore, in certain cases, it seems like the observations are sort of "imputed", i.e., there is a transition between real observations with multiple steps in between for which there are no observations.

Perhaps this is not an issue but due to my lack of understanding how it actually works. In any case, any pointers are much appreciated, thanks!

```
df <- structure(list(time = structure(c(12174, 12179, 12180, 12181, 
12189, 12191, 12193, 12198, 12199, 12200, 12201, 12202, 12203, 
12205, 12206, 12207, 12208, 12209, 12210, 12211, 12212, 12213, 
12214, 12215, 12216, 12217, 12218, 12219, 12220, 12221, 12222, 
12223, 12224, 12225, 12226, 12227, 12228, 12229, 12230, 12231, 
12232), class = "Date"), lon = c(37.0615319203799, 37.0716477974754, 
37.0615319203799, 37.0923434723092, 37.0923434723092, 37.0507170659893, 
37.1042645986751, 37.1042645986751, 37.0716477974754, 37.0507170659893, 
37.0507170659893, 37.0923434723092, 37.0716477974754, 37.047738185691, 
37.0906383964751, 37.066505639265, 37.1069135660838, 37.0808814378127, 
37.066505639265, 37.0808814378127, 37.1069135660838, 37.066505639265, 
37.1069135660838, 37.0906383964751, 37.047738185691, 37.1069135660838, 
37.1069135660838, 37.0808814378127, 37.066505639265, 37.0808814378127, 
37.047738185691, 37.066505639265, 37.0906383964751, 37.047738185691, 
37.1069135660838, 37.0808814378127, 37.066505639265, 37.0906383964751, 
37.066505639265, 37.0906383964751, 37.0808814378127), lat = c(-2.7411848459376, 
-2.71292701762913, -2.7411848459376, -2.72165547518141, -2.72165547518141, 
-2.73329474303528, -2.71147633070969, -2.71147633070969, -2.71292701762913, 
-2.73329474303528, -2.73329474303528, -2.72165547518141, -2.71292701762913, 
-2.73075363771866, -2.71197727883059, -2.7343739141538, -2.71507451885925, 
-2.71061194970373, -2.7343739141538, -2.71061194970373, -2.71507451885925, 
-2.7343739141538, -2.71507451885925, -2.71197727883059, -2.73075363771866, 
-2.71507451885925, -2.71507451885925, -2.71061194970373, -2.7343739141538, 
-2.71061194970373, -2.73075363771866, -2.7343739141538, -2.71197727883059, 
-2.73075363771866, -2.71507451885925, -2.71061194970373, -2.7343739141538, 
-2.71197727883059, -2.7343739141538, -2.71197727883059, -2.71061194970373
), group = c("D", "A", "D", "E", "E", "C", "B", "B", "A", "C", 
"C", "E", "A", "C", "A", "D", "B", "E", "D", "E", "B", "D", "B", 
"A", "C", "B", "B", "E", "D", "E", "C", "D", "A", "C", "B", "E", 
"D", "A", "D", "A", "E"), category = c("High", "High", "High", 
"High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", 
"High", "High", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", 
"Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", 
"Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", 
"Low", "Low", "Low")), row.names = c(NA, -41L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

```
gif <- df %>% 
  mutate(group=factor(group), category=factor(category)) %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin=37.00, xmax=37.21, ymin=-Inf, ymax=Inf, fill=category), alpha=0.5, show.legend=T) + 
  geom_jitter(aes(x=lon, y=lat), size=5, width=0.02, height=0.02) +
  labs(x="Longitude", y="Latitude") +
  scale_x_continuous(limits=c(37.00, 37.21), expand=c(0,0)) +
  theme(panel.background=element_blank(), 
        axis.ticks.length=unit(0.25,"cm"),
        axis.ticks.x=element_line(size=0.2),
        axis.ticks.y=element_line(size=0.2),
        axis.line.x=element_line(size=0.2),
        axis.line.y=element_line(size=0.2),
        plot.margin=margin(t=5.5, r=5.5, b=5.5, l=5.5)) +
  transition_time(time) +
  view_follow(fixed_x=T, fixed_y=T) +
  labs(title = '{frame_time}') +
  ease_aes('linear')

animate(gif, height=500, width=500, duration=70, renderer=gifski_renderer()) # use duration to slow it down
anim_save("df.gif")
```

[image: df]

Comment: I think `transition_time()` may be doing what is expected here.  It goes through the whole time range of the data by default (see `range` argument), not just the given dates.  Missing time points still progress linearly linear during tweening; this is easiest to see by looking at the `anim1` gif made in the documentation for `transition_time()`.

Comment: Yes you're right. It was as easy making `time` a `factor` and use `transition_states()`   instead of `transition_time()`.